# Is it a good idea to embed a pthread_mutex_t obj into a C++ obj instance? I think (sadly) no bat

Tags: c++, pthreads, mutex

this question has been originated by my effort to implement via pthread the following simple Mailbox interface:

```
typedef void* MailBox;

typedef enum MailBoxReturnValues {ok=0, fail4timeOut, fail} MailBoxReturnValues;


MailBox              CreateMailBox (const char* const mailBoxName);  /* returns NULL 4 fail */

MailBoxReturnValues  DeleteMailBox (MailBox   mailBox);      
MailBoxReturnValues      TxMailBox (MailBox mbx, void*    sendingObj, unsigned timeoutInTic);
MailBoxReturnValues      RxMailBox (MailBox mbx, void* *receivingObj, unsigned timeoutInTic);
```

To implement it I've created a C++ class where I placed all my suff and also a mutex which have to serialize the access to every instance. The problems are rised when I tried to write the DeleteMailBox because I can't delete a locked mutex but if I unlock it I can't garantee that someone else get the access to the deleting object.
(In my opinion the thread that have locked a mutex should also have to have the possibility do delete it).

Comment: You have multiple mutex objects associated with every `MailBox` you have, am I getting you right?

Comment: I suspect that there is only one mutex protecting the internal queue class.

Comment: A similar destruction issue also applies to any semaphores or condvars supplying blocking semantics.  Typically, my approach to such issues is to never delete such objects during an app run.

Answer (score 3):

Destruction should always be synchronized externally. A mutex (or any intrinsically synchronized object for that matter) can never synchronize its own destruction.

The race that you are worried about is that two threads may call `DeleteMailBox` and `TxMailBox` concurrently on the same `MailBox` object. As you have observed, the `MailBox` object itself cannot safeguard against this race. Even if you could destroy a locked mutex, a concurrent lock attempt by another thread would now try to lock a destroyed mutex, which is a data race.

This is a *fundamental limitation* of object-oriented designs in multithreaded contexts. If a user requests destruction of an object, it is up to the user to ensure that no one will attempt to access the object concurrently from that point on.

Note that *user* in this context can be any external entity. For example, in C++11 you can often use `weak_ptr` to work around the issue. But in principle this remains a highly non-trivial problem that requires careful consideration.